# I have the following error mysql error #2000

Tags: mysql

I get the error message. I am using phpAdmin

## 2000 - Can't find file 'c:/tmp/userlist.csv'.

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'c:/tmp/userlist.csv'
INTO TABLE users2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'

LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

I have googled and that error seems to be a lot of other things too.

It does exist as i have just pasted into windows and it opens the file.

Answer (score 1):

With `LOAD DATA LOCAL` the file is read locally and it needs to be accessible by the client. You mentioned you are using phpMyAdmin (a MySQL client), so the file needs to be accessible from wherever phpMyAdmin is running from.

If phpMyAdmin isn't installed on your computer, then you need to upload the file to the server where it's located and change the file path accordingly.

---

Another solution would be to install a MySQL client on your computer to run the query, so it can read the file locally. I recommend [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

Comment: I have uploaded it to the route of the server with a few folders     #2000 - Can't find file '\gamesdata\1 data users1 csv\userlist.csv' still get the error. I have used no slashes or double back slash or s slash forward etc...

Comment: #1045 - Access denied for user 'ckidsuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)  I just uploaded file and tok out the keyword LOCAL now it's on the server route. This is the error I get now.

Comment: by the way the following links says I can upload from my local computer to a remore dbase - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/

Comment: You can, but the client needs to be on the same machine as the file. You can also try with MySQL Workbench to read the file on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I had to do in the end was press IMPORT inside phpMyadmin. It would have been nicer if somebody had told me that instead of mucking around for two days trying to import a csv via sqls.